# Receiving arduino(esp8266) sensor data from Firebase

Tags: firebase, arduino, esp8266

I am using esp8266 and DHT11 sensor to push data to Firebase and get the data back.

I've successfully push the sensor data to firebase. The problem I am having is that whenever I push the data to Firebase it automatically creates an AutoChild to the database.

```
int humidity = dht.readHumidity();
float h = dht.readHumidity();
float t = dht.readTemperature();         
Serial.print("Current humidity = ");
Serial.print(h);
Serial.print("%  ");
Serial.print("temperature = ");
Serial.print(t); 
Serial.println("C  ");
Firebase.pushFloat("/devices/sensors/humid", humidity);
```

This is my code. I just want to push the sensor data in the path I created("/devices/sensors/humid"). But it keeps creating a auto child under my path.

Comment: Isn't there something like setFloat()?

Comment: Yes, that worked! For some reason I thought that I tried that and didn't work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you write the solution up in an answer? Possibly linking to relevant documentation. That way other people who have the same problem can find the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code Firebase.push will create an autochild

```
Firebase.pushFloat("/devices/sensors/humid", humidity);
```

Changing the code to Firebase.set will not create an extra autochild. This will just set the value to the path I created in firebase.

```
Firebase.setFloat("/devices/sensors/humid", humidity);
```